# can't get query to order posts by acf datepicker

Tags: query, advanced-custom-fields, order

I've read alot, I've tried a bunch of different things, I still can't get my query to order posts by acf's datepicker field. This is what my code looks like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   =>  'arm_careers',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'post_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_type' => 'DATE',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

I'm not using PRO, I'm using the free one. The save format is `yymmdd`, I've also tried `YYYYMMDD` but neither worked.

Here is what it currently looks like:
August 14, 2018
August 2, 2018
August 9, 2018

when I want it to look like:
August 2, 2018
August 9, 2018
August 14, 2018

The display format is `MM d, yy`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your saved format to the post_date format which is in

`Y-m-d H:i:s`

Only then will the comparators work properly with automatically generated query objects.

Comment: Change `orderby=> 'meta_value_num'` to `'meta_value'`

Answer (score 1):

ACF stores dates as yyyymmdd in meta values, so it's very probable that casting it to DATE won't work properly...

And there is no need to compare it as number - dictionary sorting will work here.

Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'arm_careers',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'post_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

PS. I'm pretty sure that you can't set the format that ACF will use to store dates. You can set the format for showing these values or for getting them.